# Swirch back to iframe selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing a problem and I don't know where I am going wrong:

```
   Thread.sleep(10000);
    String mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

    while(true) {
        try {
            wc.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@class='iff-campaign-container']/a")));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='iff-campaign-container']/a")).click();
//Here on click , it open new window in new browser.
            for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
                driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); 
            }
            driver.close();
            driver.switchTo().window(mainWindow);
            driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
```

My wait condition fail after first loop run .
I am doing this , xpath is in iframe , and used iframe because , after every click new webelement is added.

Comment: Just  debug your code in eclipse and see where it causing problem

Comment: use break statement in last line of try block

Answer (score 1):

In the line `driver.switchTo().frame(0);` you are changing the `TargetLocator` for the driver to the `iframe`, which doesn't have the specified `xpath` so the wait condition fails.

If you don't do anything within the `iframe` just remove it. If you do use it at the end switch back

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
// do stuff on the iframe
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```